# MongoDB: Is a range query possible using multikeys?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

```
var jd = {
  type: "Person",
  attributes: {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 30
  }
};

var pd = {
  type: "Person",
  attributes: {
    name: "Penelope Doe",
    age: 26
  }
};

var ss = {
  type: "Book",
  attributes: {
    name: "The Sword Of Shannara",
    author: "Terry Brooks"
  }
};

db.things.save(jd);
db.things.save(pd);
db.things.save(ss);
db.things.ensureIndex({attributes: 1})
db.things.find({"attributes.age": 30}) // => John Doe
db.things.find({"attributes.age": 30}).explain() // => BasicCursor... (don't want a scan)
db.things.find({"attributes.age": {$gte: 18}) // John Doe, Penelope Doe (via a scan)
```

The goal is that all attributes be indexed and searchable via range queries and that the index actually be used (as opposed to a collection scan).  There's no telling what attributes a document will have.  I have read about multikeys but they seem only to work (by index) with exact-match queries.

Multikeys prefers this format for a document:

```
var pd = {
  type: "Person",
  attributes: [
    {name: "Penelope Doe"},
    {age: 26}
  ]
};
```

Is there a pattern where by one index I can find items by attribute using a range?

EDIT:

In a schemaless DB it makes sense to have potentially a limitless array of types, yet a collection name practically implies some sort of type.  But if we go to the extreme, we want to allow for any number of types within a collection (so that we don't have to define a collection for every conceivable custom type a user might imagine).  Searching, therefore, by attributes (of any sort) with just a single deep index (that supports ranged queries) makes this sort of thing far more feasible.  Seems to me a natural fit for a schemaless DB.

Opened a ticket if you wanna vote it up:

http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2675

Comment: I would post this question in http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user and get an answer from the developers themselves - they are *very* responsive.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I did just that. :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Range queries are possible using multikeys; however, expressing the query can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Yes range queries work with multikeys.  However multikeys are for arrays rather than embedded objects.

In the example above try

```
db.things.ensureIndex({"attributes.age": 1})
```

Comment: The goal is to avoid indexing "age" or any one attribute in particular but to have all "attributes" indexed. The point is I could have any attribute key (e.g. "dob", "name", "hair_color") and I should have indexed access to them all.